# Shutdown signal in golang

Tags: go

I'm running my golang executable and it is blocked by this code:

```
    signalChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalChannel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-signalChannel

    err := ensureDir("./jake")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
```

It creates the jake directory if the user hit  `ctl + c` but I would like to know how can 
I make the program do the same thing if the os was shut down by the user.

Comment: It the OS is shut down, all running processes are send SIGTERM.

Answer (score 0):

Here, read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499764/398386

Handle `SIGTERM`, properly.

Also, from the code block, I think you have some implementation problems as well. Could you please see if you're handling it in a separate goroutine, or share more piece of code so we could see.

Also, for your reference, see this: https://gist.github.com/reiki4040/be3705f307d3cd136e85#file-signal-go

This is a very simple and working example related to signals.

Comment: SIGKILL, like SIGSTOP, cannot be handled